# Rails 3 start mongrel with --prefix option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongrel

I know that mongrel is not compatible with Rails 3. So I can't run mongrel_rails start in Rails 3. If I do so, i will get dispather error. I have to make mongrel the default server and do

script/rails server -p 3001

Then it works. However, my question is that mongrel has other options like --prefix, how do i make mongrel knows about this option under script/rails? I try to use

script/rails server -p 3001 --prefix /my_app

This doesn't work as --prefix is not a known conf to script/rails server. Anybody has any idea? Thanks a lot.